# How can I Send & Receive SMS from QT mobile application for symbian?

Tags: c++, qt, sms

I'm developing a mobile applicatiom for symbian but I have a problem about sending and receiving SMS. I searched on internet but didn't find good solutions because lots of them were archived.

Waiting your help.

Best Regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The messaging library provides a set of APIs for accessing messaging
>   data. Interfaces are provided to retrieve and query messages, folders
>   and accounts, also interfaces to create, modify, and store messages
>   are provided. A unified interface for manipulation and storage of SMS,
>   MMS, MIME Email and TNEF Email messages is provided. Handling of
>   messages that have only been partially retrieved is supported.

http://doc.qt.digia.com/qtmobility-1.2/messaging.html

Comment: Thanks for your help. Is there any sample code about this? For example, sending and receiving sms?

Comment: I found a link that is http://doc.qt.digia.com/qtmobility-1.2/serviceactions.html. I think this link help me?

Comment: I think. It is on the examples side. I think, It's about this qtmobility? is it different?

Comment: Yes. Qt Mobility is a part of Qt SDK for Symbian.